# Video play button misplaced under iOS 8

Tags: iphone, html5-video, ios8

Somehow the html video tag seems to be buggy in iOS 8 (UIWebView). There is no way to focus the "play" button on the video image. It always looks like that:

[image]

If we run the exact same code in iOS 7.1, it looks like that:

[image]

The HTML we load into the UIWebView looks like that:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video style="width:100px;height:100px;" controls="" poster="http://goo.gl/Rz0Tkv">
            <source src="/tmp/2f4194b4-cabd-4c34-9f34-78561b8a900f.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

We found no way to resize that play-button. Height/Width in CSS, direct HTML, even put the whole video-tag into a div and style this had no effect.

It's also interesting that in iOS 8, the poster-tag is necessary for a video, otherwise there is no thumbnail (in iOS 7, there was by default a thumbnail of the video).

Looks to me like a bug, do you have an idea for a quick workaround? Besides opening a ticket at apple ofc...

**Update**
It seems to be the same problem for the *iframe* tag.

Comment: have the same problem. Did You find a way to fix it ?

Comment: havent found a solution yet... we made a workaround and just increased the video preview, so the play-icon is still in the middle... but we found no way to move the icon with css or html